# Linked Server In SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-express, linked-server

I am developing an app where i have a local database in SQL Server Express. During work in local database, we need to execute a query on another SQL Server / live server  and its return a value and with this value we execute a query in local server.

It is OK when executing this query against 2 or 3 queries, but i have around 5000 records on which I need to execute same process. I have done with above style but its take too much time.

I've found that we can run a query on multiple servers.

Can i run a query on SQL Server Express and server at same time and and run my whole queries in this style?

I can run query from express to server only.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can. Setup the LinkServer on the SQL Express then just pass your query in the four part name format

> server . database . schema . object

example

```
select * from LinkServer.mydatabase.dbo.Table
```

Comment: I am sure SQL Server Express does not allow you to create Linked Servers, due to it being free! Please correct me if I am wrong, as I have a client that wants to connect SQL Server to MS Access.

Comment: @Fandango68 - I'm using a linked server in SQL Server Express 2016.

Comment: Thanks @TomaszGandor - good to know